# Local url to media results in 404 while cloudinary url to media succeeds

Tags: strapi, cloudinary

I have a strapi cms hosted at `172.20.0.20:1337`

I've uploaded an image to Strapi via `172.20.0.20:1337/admin` panel. The resulting url for the uploaded image becomes:

`https://res.cloudinary.com/dfttslyj8/image/upload/v1710951335/neon_paint_takeover_4k_2_72acd90a9c.png`

This works.

However the clients are all on LAN and do not have internet access so I need to be able to access the asset locally:

`172.20.0.20:1337/uploads/neon_paint_takeover_4k_2_72acd90a9c.png`

This gives me a 404 json response:

```
{"data":null,"error":{"status":404,"name":"NotFoundError","message":"Not Found","details":{}}}
```

Can someone help me understand why strapi media on the local network doesn't seem to exist, only on cloudinary? What troubleshooting steps can be taken?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It sounds like you're using the Cloudinary Upload Plugin, then trying to download the files from Cloudinary from devices that are not able to access Cloudinary's servers. 
If that's the case, why not use the Local plugin instead? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@strapi/provider-upload-local

Comment: Thank you I'll look into that! Yeah the cloudinary plugin is running but I need to simply not use it for these devices, and instead just grab them locally. Wasn't aware that I'd need a diff plugin to do that (I didn't set this up). Could I keep cloudinary running but also use the local plugin at the same time?